# Disable a button if the two values coming from my views.py are equal

Tags: django, python-3.x, jinja2

How can i disable a button if the two values coming from my views.py are equal. Is it possible to make it work like this?

```
<button {% if value1 == value2 %} {{'disabled'}} {% endif %} type="button">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need `{{''}}` around `disabled` attribute. Just try this:

```
<button {% if value1 == value2 %} disabled {% endif %} type="button">Add</button>
```